# resubmit form doesn't work after e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flask

I want to re-submit the form, after e.preventDefault, but it doesn't work, I spend the whole afternoon, still failed to get it working.

flask code

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "assa"


@app.route("/", methods=["POST", "GET"])

    def single_input():
        if request.method == "POST":
            print(request.form)
            return render_template("index.html")
        return render_template("index.html")
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="/">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Do Something">
    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Do Something Else">
</form>
<script>
const Form = document.getElementById('form1');
Form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault();
Form.submit();
});
</script>
```

it output:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

I would expect when I press "Do Something", it output

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('submit_button', 'Do Something')])
```

Comment: If you resubmit the form, it will trigger the same function again and the form submit will again be prevented. You created an infinite loop this way. You will have to submit the form via a different way.

Comment: I know little at this areal